# fetching millions of records from the database using php

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I am facing problem with fetching millions of records from the mysql database using php,I want to load this records into excel file.When I am executing query,if the result set is having few records (in hundreds)then it's saved into the excel file,but when I am fetching million records it's display an error called

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator to inform of the time the error occurred and of anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

and My code is:

```
<?php
/*
author: shobhan
Date: 20-10-2014
Description: This file creates excel sheet from the database based on the selection and available for download
*/
ini_set('max_execution_time', 6000);
ini_set('memory_limit','1000M');
set_time_limit(0);
//echo ini_get('memory_limit');
include("db/config.php");   //include global configuration file
global $db_host,$db_name,$db_user,$db_password; //include global variables
$con=mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_password,$db_name);
$flag=1;

$download_filename="";

                header("Content-type: text/csv");
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=suburban_data.csv");
                // Disable caching
                header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1
                header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0
                header("Expires: 0"); // Proxies

                //echo $query; 
                //echo "<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>";
                $result_array=array();
                $output = fopen("php://output", "w");
                $headings=array("Patient Name","Mobile","Visit Date","Centre","Profiles","Gender","Age");
                fputcsv($output, $headings);



function preparewhere($ptstring){
global $db_host,$db_name,$db_user,$db_password; //include global variables
global $download_filename;
global $flag;
    $year=$_POST['year'];
    $centre=$_POST['centre_ids'];
    $gender=$_POST['gender'];
    $profile=$_POST['profile_ids'];
    $testresult=$_POST['testresult'];
    $age=$_POST['age'];
    $treatmenttype=$_POST['treatmenttype'];
    $where="";
    $year_condition="";
    $centre_condition="";
    $gender_condition="";
    $test_condition="";
    $testresult_condition="";
    $age_condition="";


    if($year=="0"){
        $year_condition="Visit.VstDate >=  '2013-01-01'";
    }
    else if($year=="2013"){
        $year_condition="Visit.VstDate >=  '2013-01-01' and Visit.VstDate <  '2014-01-01'";
        $download_filename.="2013";
    }
    else{
        $year_condition="Visit.VstDate >=  '2014-01-01'";
        $download_filename.="2014";
    }

    //centre condition
    if($centre!=0){
        $centre_condition=" and centres.SysNo in(".$centre.")";
        $download_filename.="_".$centre;
    }


    //gender condition
    if($gender!="0"){
        $gender_condition=" and patient.PatSex= '".$gender."'";
        $download_filename.="_".$gender;
    }
        if($flag==2){   //if input contains only profiles
        $test_condition=" and VisitProfile.ProfCode in(".$ptstring.")";
    }
    else{
        $test_condition=" and Test.TestCode in(".$ptstring.")";
    }

    //test result 
    if($flag==1){
    if($testresult!="0"){
        if($testresult=="HL"){
            $testresult_condition=" and (result.AbnormalFlag='H' or result.AbnormalFlag ='L')";
            $download_filename.="_abnormal";
        }else{
            $testresult_condition=" and result.AbnormalFlag='N'";
            $download_filename.="_normal";
        }       
    }
    }

    //age 
    if($age!="0"){
        if($age=="0-30")
            $age_condition=" and Visit.Age>=0 and Visit.Age<=30";
        else if($age=="31-40")
            $age_condition=" and Visit.Age>=31 and Visit.Age<=40";
        else if($age=="41-50")
            $age_condition=" and Visit.Age>=41 and Visit.Age<=50";
        else if($age=="51-60")
            $age_condition=" and Visit.Age>=51 and Visit.Age<=60";
        else
            $age_condition=" and Visit.Age>60";
    }
    $where=$year_condition.$centre_condition.$gender_condition.$test_condition.$testresult_condition.$age_condition;    
    return $where;      
}

//echo "where condition ".preparewhere();
//echo "<br/>";


function preparequery(){
global $flag;
$selectquery="";
    if($flag==1){
        $selectquery="select Distinct(patient.PatName), Visit.VstMobile, Visit.VstDate, centres.SysField, Test.TestName, patient.Patsex, Visit.Age from Visit
        inner join centres on Visit.RegistrationCentreCode=centres.SysNo
        inner join patient on Visit.VstPatCode=patient.Patcode
        inner join result on result.TrJobCode=Visit.VstCode
        inner join Test on Test.TestCode=result.TrTestCode
        inner join Param on Param.ParamCode=result.TrParamCode
        ";      
    }
    else{
        $selectquery="select Distinct(patient.PatName), Visit.VstMobile, Visit.VstDate, centres.SysField, profiles.ProfName, patient.Patsex, Visit.Age from Visit
        inner join centres on Visit.RegistrationCentreCode=centres.SysNo
        inner join patient on Visit.VstPatCode=patient.Patcode
        inner join VisitProfile on VisitProfile.VstCode=Visit.VstCode
        inner join profiles on profiles.ProfCode=VisitProfile.ProfCode
        ";      
    }
    return $selectquery;
}

function strpos_offset($needle, $haystack, $occurrence) {
  // explode the haystack
  $arr = explode($needle, $haystack);
  // check the needle is not out of bounds
  switch( $occurrence ) {
    case $occurrence == 0:
      return false;
    case $occurrence > max(array_keys($arr)):
      return false;
    default:
      return strlen(implode($needle, array_slice($arr, 0, $occurrence)));
  }
}


header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=suburban_data.csv");
// Disable caching
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1
header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0
header("Expires: 0"); // Proxies

if(!mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
            $count=0;
            $pcount=substr_count($_POST['profile_ids'], 'p');   //stores number of profiles from the string
            $ptcount=substr_count($_POST['profile_ids'], ',');  //stores number of tests or profiles selected

            if($pcount==0)
                $flag=1;
            else if($pcount==$ptcount+1)
                $flag=2;
            else
                $flag=3;

            if($flag==1 || $flag ==2){              //if the selection contains either profiles or tests
                //echo "profiles".$ptstring;
                if($flag==1)
                {

                $tstring=$_POST['profile_ids'];
                //echo "test".$tstring;
                $mobile="";
                $query_count_mobilenumbers=preparequery()." where ".preparewhere($tstring);
                $con=mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_password,$db_name);
                $start = 0;
                $limit = 1000;

                    do {
                        $mobile_result = mysqli_query(
                            $con,
                            $query_count_mobilenumbers." LIMIT {$start}, {$limit}",
                            MYSQLI_USE_RESULT      // this always helps for this kind of processing (makes a smooth streaming)
                        );

                        $nbRows = 0;       // cannot use mysqli_num_rows() because of `MYSQLI_USE_RESULT`

                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($mobile_result)) {
                        fputcsv($output, array($row[0],$row[1],$row[2],$row[3],$row[4],$row[5],$row[6])); 
                        $nbRows ++;
                        }

    // next batch
                    $start += $limit;
                    } while ($nbRows); 
                    }
                else{
                $ptstring=str_replace("p","",$_POST['profile_ids']);
                //echo "profiles are".$_POST['profile_ids'];
                $query_count_mobilenumbers=preparequery()." where ".preparewhere($ptstring);
                //echo "query is".$query_count_mobilenumbers;
                $con=mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_password,$db_name);
                $start = 0;
                $limit = 1000;

                    do {
                        $mobile_result = mysqli_query(
                            $con,
                            $query_count_mobilenumbers." LIMIT {$start}, {$limit}",
                            MYSQLI_USE_RESULT      // this always helps for this kind of processing (makes a smooth streaming)
                        );

                        $nbRows = 0;       // cannot use mysqli_num_rows() because of `MYSQLI_USE_RESULT`

                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($mobile_result)) {
                        fputcsv($output, array($row[0],$row[1],$row[2],$row[3],$row[4],$row[5],$row[6])); 
                        $nbRows ++;
                        }

    // next batch
                    $start += $limit;
                    } while ($nbRows); 


                }

            }   
            else{                                   //if the selection contains both profiles and tests             
                //echo "inside both";
                $no_of_profiles=substr_count($_POST['profile_ids'], 'p');
                $nth_comma_index=strpos_offset(',',$_POST['profile_ids'], $no_of_profiles); //gets the nth comma's index
                $pstring=str_replace("p","",substr($_POST['profile_ids'],0,$nth_comma_index));
                $tstring=substr($_POST['profile_ids'],$nth_comma_index+1);
                $mobile="";
                $flag=1;
                //query as tests

                //echo "inside flag";
                $query1=preparequery()." where ".preparewhere($tstring);
                $con=mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_password,$db_name);
                //echo "quer".$query1;
                $mobile_result1 = mysqli_query($con,$query1);
                $start = 0;
                $limit = 1000;

                    do {
                        $mobile_result1 = mysqli_query(
                            $con,
                            $query1." LIMIT {$start}, {$limit}",
                            MYSQLI_USE_RESULT      // this always helps for this kind of processing (makes a smooth streaming)
                        );

                        $nbRows = 0;       // cannot use mysqli_num_rows() because of `MYSQLI_USE_RESULT`

                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($mobile_result1)) {
                        fputcsv($output, array($row[0],$row[1],$row[2],$row[3],$row[4],$row[5],$row[6])); 
                        $nbRows ++;
                        }

    // next batch
                    $start += $limit;
                    } while ($nbRows); 


                $flag=2;

                    //echo "inside flag2";
                $query2=preparequery()." where ".preparewhere($pstring);
                $start = 0;
                $limit = 1000;

                    do {
                        $mobile_result2 = mysqli_query(
                            $con,
                            $query2." LIMIT {$start}, {$limit}",
                            MYSQLI_USE_RESULT      // this always helps for this kind of processing (makes a smooth streaming)
                        );

                        $nbRows = 0;       // cannot use mysqli_num_rows() because of `MYSQLI_USE_RESULT`

                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($mobile_result2)) {
                        fputcsv($output, array($row[0],$row[1],$row[2],$row[3],$row[4],$row[5],$row[6])); 
                        $nbRows ++;
                        }


                    $start += $limit;
                    } while ($nbRows); 



                }
    }
    else{
        echo "failed to connect to database";
    }

fclose($output);


?>
```

Comment: So check the server error logs; but why don't you simply use `fputcsv($output, $row);` rather than recreating an array that already exists?

Comment: Probably because the query returns more columns than he wants to put into the CSV file. Better adjust the query if this is the case.

Answer (score 2):

I bet the error you can find in the server's error log says something about the PHP script running out of memory. This happens because by default the query to the database completes when all the rows are received from the database server. And because you asked for millions of rows the result set is huge and takes a lot of memory on the PHP process.

**I think** you should use `MYSQLI_USE_RESULT` as the third parameter of your call to `mysqli_query()`:

```
$mobile_result = mysqli_query($con, $query_count_mobilenumbers, MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);
```

This makes `mysqli_query()` return faster (probably as soon as the first row from the result is received from the server) and the returned result set stores the received rows only until they are retrieved by the program using `mysqli_fetch_*()` functions.

I never used `mysqli`, the old `mysql` extension had a separate function for this purpose (called `mysql_unbuffered_query()`) but the `mysql` extension is dead so **do not** use it.

If this approach still does not work then you can try to get the data from the server in batches using `LIMIT`.

```
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=suburban_data.csv");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1
header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0
header("Expires: 0"); // Proxies

// The next line is very important: it prevents PHP abruptly stop the script
// before it finishes what it's doing
set_time_limit(0);
$output = fopen("php://output", "w");

$headings=array("PatientName","Email","VisitDate","Centre","Profiles","Parameter","Age");
fputcsv($output, $headings);

$start = 0;
$limit = 1000;

do {
    $mobile_result = mysqli_query(
        $con,
        $query_count_mobilenumbers." LIMIT {$start}, {$limit}",
        MYSQLI_USE_RESULT      // this always helps for this kind of processing (makes a smooth streaming)
    );

    $nbRows = 0;       // cannot use mysqli_num_rows() because of `MYSQLI_USE_RESULT`

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($mobile_result)) {
        fputcsv($output, array($row[0],$row[1],$row[2],$row[3],$row[4],$row[5],$row[6])); 
        $nbRows ++;
    }

    // next batch
    $start += $limit;
} while ($nbRows);           // Stop when the query didn't return any row

fclose($output);
```

Comment: Even though ,I retrieved the records in batches to the excel ,it is taking to too much time,and displaying same error like internal server.For some records it's working but it's not working for bulk data

Comment: Put `set_time_limit(0);` somewhere in your script, before starting the data retrieval. By default, when it's invoked by the web server, PHP allows the scripts to run for 30 seconds. You need more than that to retrieve millions of records, that's why you should put that line of code. It removes the time limit and your script is allowed to run until it finishes what it's doing. I forgot about that :-)

Comment: I have used set_time_limit (0), still the same response

Comment: Then maybe there is another problem somewhere in the code. Can you check the server logs? Apache's `error_log` probably doesn't say more than "Internal server error" but it's also possible to have the PHP error message there. Also there should be a PHP error log somewhere, its name is `php_errors.log`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try **ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');** in your PHP script before the fetch/select query, if you are using shared hosting else set **post_max_size** in php.ini. **ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');** working fine for me.

For the safe side, you can also set the memory size instead of **-1**.